# How to set particular session for end user

Tags: security, configuration

In my org some end users are there, i have to set timeout for 30 mins. After 30 mins it will logout forcefully. 
Can we set different session timings for different end users. Is it possible, if it is how we can and where we have to change. please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to a profile, click Edit, and then choose the appropriate time out value. Assign the profile to users that should have a longer time out session. This is under Setup > Manage Users > Profiles.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox. Can we do same thing at user level settings.i mean for individual user.

Comment: @ApexCode Nope, you need a profile.

Answer (score -1):

From Setup, enter Session Settings in the Quick Find box, then select Session Settings. There you can set the Timeout Value.

Comment: Hi @snl, if i change in security control it will apply for all users in the org right. But i need user level or profile level. Thank you